# How Docker iptables work by default?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I am on Ubuntu 22.04
I am trying to understand iptables

iptables -L (Docker related)

```
Chain DOCKER (9 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.20.0.2           tcp dpt:51413
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:9000
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             172.20.0.2           udp dpt:51413
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.20.0.2           tcp dpt:9091
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.21.0.3           tcp dpt:6443

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (9 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I have many network and minikube and k3s on my computer.
How are these rules created?
Let's take a look et /etc/systemd/

```
cat cri-docker.service 
[Unit]
Description=CRI Interface for Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.mirantis.com
After=network-online.target firewalld.service docker.service
Wants=network-online.target
Requires=cri-docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/cri-dockerd --container-runtime-endpoint fd://
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always
```

is this service created by deafault? How is the Docker setup working?